# Error reading R script (),system error 2 when trying to run R Studio on Mac

Tags: macos, rstudio, macos-big-sur

I installed R Studio desktop in my MacBook air running on Big Sur. Unfortunately, it cannot run due to the error below:

> Error reading R script (),system error 2 (No such file or directory);
> Unable to find libR.dylib in expected locationswithin R Home directory
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources

[image]

Answer (score 33):

Running `brew install R` solves the problem for me.

Comment: I had the same problem. I tried this but it didn't work, so I reinstalled it: `brew reinstall r` , now it is working fine

Answer (score 10):

A similar question was asked [on the R Studio community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-studio-for-mac/106768).

- You need to first download base R:

  - Choose the latest version from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/), under the ***Latest release*** header. For example, `R-4.1.0.pkg`.
- Then download R Studio for MacOS from [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download).

Comment: latest error 
## R Session Startup Failure Report

### RStudio Version

RStudio 1.4.1717, "Juliet Rose" (df86b69e, 2021-05-24) for macOS

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_4_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.10 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

### Error message

[No error available]

### Process Output

The R session exited with code 1. 

Error output:

```
arch: Unknown architecture: arm64

```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

### Logs

*Log File*

```
[No logs available]
```

Comment: Can I use R from conda-forge as the base R?

Answer (score 9):

You have probably installed `Rstudio` before installing `R`. What you can do is to first **install R** using `brew install R` and then **reinstalling Rstudio** using `brew reinstall rstudio`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to all above info, with recent releases of MacOS we will have to install XQuartz before installing R. After these installations, proceed with RStudio installation.